# How do I pass props from from redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a simple app that's using redux and react-router. I wrapped my app component in a provider tag so that it has access to the store. I connected (in App.js) the mapStateToProps and mapStateToDispatch in the App.js. I'm not sure how to pass the function I defined in App.js to a child component since I'm using route. I tried doing the render trick but it didn't work. If I can pass it to that CelebrityPage component, how would I receive it in the file? Any help would be appreciated.

This is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import './App.css';
import Clarifai from 'clarifai'

// import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
// import particlesOptions from './particleOptions'
import { Signin } from './components/signin/Signin';
import Register from './components/register/Register';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import { setSearchField } from './context/Actions'
import FacePage from './Containers/FacePage';
import CelebrityPage from './Containers/CelebrityPage';
import ControllerPage from './Containers/ControllerPage';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    input: state.input
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    handleSearchChange: (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value))
  }
}
...
 render() {

    return (<Router>
      <Switch >
        <Route path='/celebrity' exact render={props => <CelebrityPage{...props} handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange} />} />
        <Route path='/' exact component={Register} />
        <Route path='/signin' exact component={Signin} />
        <Route path='/contoller' exact component={ControllerPage} />
        <Route path='/face-detection' exact component={FacePage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>)
  }

}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Comment: just wrapp you child component ,FacePAge , ControllePage or any child component of this page component witth connect function... the lower in component tree you will wrap component by connect the better performece you will get.

Comment: you can call connect in any of your component. so if is part  of state that use only one button then just wrap this button witch connect function. if state will change ony this one button will be re rendered.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to pass store actions and states into the child components, it means you are refusing to use the advantages of redux. The best approach should be connect any of your component that needs to access to the actions or state to the store. Doing connection at the root component level and passing the props to the child components is not a good solution.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean now, I thought I could only connect it to the root component I had no idea it was this versatile so thank you for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

I think what robert is saying is what you'd probably want to do. Don't try to pass your props inside of your `<Route>`. Instead do your `connect` `mapDispatchToProps` and your `mapStateToProps`  inside your CelebrityPage Component.

Once you do the wrapping inside of the Celebrity Page component you should have access to the props and functions that you have defined.

```
... 
// keep all the previous imports from your App.Js
 render() {

// have your router like this
    return (<Router>
      <Switch >
        <Route path='/celebrity' exact component ={CelebrityPage} />
        <Route path='/' exact component={Register} />
        <Route path='/signin' exact component={Signin} />
        <Route path='/contoller' exact component={ControllerPage} />
        <Route path='/face-detection' exact component={FacePage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>)
  }
}
export default App
```

Example Celebrity page

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
class CelebrityPage extends React.Component {
  
// put your mapStateToProps and mapDispatch function heres instead of app.js

mapStateToProps() {

}
mapDispatchToProps {
 // bind your handlesearch function to props here
}
 render() {
   return (
  <div>
    <input />
    <button onClick={this.props.handleSearchChange}/>
  </div>
  )
 }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CelebrityPage)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Nathan. This worked exactly how I wanted it to. I'm fairly new to Redux so I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @TapiwaKundishora no problem at all. Happy to help